# dataframe divided from one column to three columns

Tags: python, dataframe

Want to divided key `'a'` value from `['11 - 18 [1.3']` into `'a1': ['11' ,'12','13','14','8']` `'a2': ['18' ,'17','18','16','48']` `'a3': ['1.3' ,'2.8','3.3','4.7','5.4']`

**Reference regex of this format**

[regexr.com/61kpi](http://regexr.com/61kpi)

[regexr.com/61kpo](http://regexr.com/61kpo)

**data**

```
x = {'a': ['11 - 18 [1.3]','12 - 17 [2.8]','13 - 18 [3.3]','14 - 16 [4.7]','8 - 48 [5.3]'],
 'b': [13.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, 15.0]}
```

**print data**

```
              a     b
0  11 - 18 [1.3]  13.0
1  12 - 17 [2.8]  11.0
2  13 - 18 [3.3]  12.0
3  14 - 16 [4.7]  14.0
4   8 - 48 [5.3]  15.0
```

**Expected Result**

```
   a1 a2   a3     b
0  11  18  1.3  13.0
1  12  17  2.8  11.0
2  13  18  3.3  12.0
3  14  16  4.7  14.0
4   8  48  5.3  15.0
```

**expected output data**

```
y = {'a1': ['11' ,'12','13','14','8'],'a2': ['18' ,'17','18','16','48'], 'a3': ['1.3' ,'2.8','3.3','4.7','5.3'], 'b': [13.0, 11.0, 21.0, 13.0, 17.0]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions will be the best way to achieve this:

Using `.str.extract` with named capture groups:

```
pattern = r"(?P<a1>\d+) - (?P<a2>\d+) \[(?P<a3>\d\.\d)\]"

new_df = df["a"].str.extract(pattern).join(df["b"])

print(new_df)
   a1  a2   a3     b
0  11  18  1.3  13.0
1  12  17  2.8  11.0
2  13  18  3.3  12.0
3  14  16  4.7  14.0
4   8  48  5.3  15.0
```

Using `.str.extractall` to get all digits in case the pattern in your dataframe is not consistent:

```
new_df = (
    df["a"].str.extractall(r"(\d+\.?\d*)")[0]
    .unstack()
    .rename(columns=lambda c: "a{}".format(c+1))
    .join(df["b"])
)

print(new_df)
   a1  a2   a3     b
0  11  18  1.3  13.0
1  12  17  2.8  11.0
2  13  18  3.3  12.0
3  14  16  4.7  14.0
4   8  48  5.3  15.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to split your text into new columns, then convert the strings to numbers, for example:

```
x = {'a': ['11 - 18 [1.3]','12 - 17 [2.8]','13 - 18 [3.3]','14 - 16 [4.7]','8 - 48 [5.3]'],
 'b': [13.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, 15.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df[['a1', 'a2']] = df['a'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)
df[['a2', 'a3']] = df['a2'].str.split(' \[', expand=True)
df['a3'] = df['a3'].str.replace(']', '')
df[['a1', 'a2', 'a3']] = df[['a1', 'a2', 'a3']].astype(float)
```

To get:

```
               a     b    a1    a2   a3
0  11 - 18 [1.3]  13.0  11.0  18.0  1.3
1  12 - 17 [2.8]  11.0  12.0  17.0  2.8
2  13 - 18 [3.3]  12.0  13.0  18.0  3.3
3  14 - 16 [4.7]  14.0  14.0  16.0  4.7
4   8 - 48 [5.3]  15.0   8.0  48.0  5.3
```